# Update the key playerEffectiveDetails with an additional object when new date

Tags: javascript, html, json, redux, rect

**update1:**

everytime when I see new date value I need to update the playerbirthDate value with that date respectively `car3 dates value---> (2) ["03/24/2019", "03/25/2019"]`

```
 values.playerEffectiveDetails = [{
      // playerbirthDate: "2019-03-01",
      playerbirthDate: this.props.cars.car2,
      multiYearNumber: 1,
      isMultiyearRecord: "Y",
      isMemberThresholdRecord: "N"
    },
    {
      // playerbirthDate: "2019-03-01",
      playerbirthDate: this.props.cars.car2,
      multiYearNumber: 1,
      isMultiyearRecord: "Y",
      isMemberThresholdRecord: "N"
    },

    {
      isMultiyearRecord: "N",
      isMemberThresholdRecord: "Y",
      memberthresholdvalue: "2500"

    }
  ];
```

I need to pass multiple dates in my object.
Whenever I see a new date I need to update the key playerEffectiveDetails in my post request, with an additional object.

Right now I am getting two different values for the dates.We will get multiple date values.

```
`console.log('car3 dates value--->', dates);
    car3 dates value---> (2) ["03/24/2019", "03/25/2019"]`
```

For each date I need to create one new additional object and pass it in my post request key playerEffectiveDetails, this one accepts array of objects
`values.playerEffectiveDetails = [{},{}];`

I created a foreach and added an Object.create. but right now I am facing two errors.

Can you tell me how to pass this new dates in the request, since playerEffectiveDetails is an array with several objects present in it.

Providing my code snippet and sample request below

```js
onSubmit(values) {
  //let playerEffectiveDetails = [];
  console.log('car3 values---->', values);

  let current = moment(new Date()).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
  console.log('current values--->', current);

  values.playerMultiYear = values.terms === 'MULTI-PERIOD' ? 'Y' : 'N';
  values.playerEvergreen = values.terms === 'EVERGREEN' ? 'Y' : 'N';

  console.log('car3 this.props.cars -->', this.props.cars);
  console.log('car1 contact type value -->', this.props.cars.car1);
  console.log('car3 this.props.cars.car2 -->', this.props.cars.car2);
  console.log("Object.keys(this.props.cars.car2).length---->", Object.keys(this.props.cars.car2).length);

  let effectivecar = [];
  effectivecar = this.props.cars.car2;
  console.log('car3 effectivecar array -->', effectivecar);
  console.log("Object.keys(effectivecar).length---->", Object.keys(effectivecar).length);

  var buz = {
    fog: 'stack',
    bog: 'use'
  };

  let outside;
  let dates = [];

  for (let name in this.props.cars.car2) {
    if (this.props.cars.car2.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      console.log('this is fog (' +
        name + ') for sure. Value: ' + this.props.cars.car2[name]);

      //outside = this.props.cars.car2[name];
      dates.push(this.props.cars.car2[name]);
    } else {
      console.log(name); // toString or something else
    }
  }

  console.log('car3 dates value--->', dates);

  //car3 dates value---> (2) ["03/24/2019", "03/25/2019"]

  // dates.map(x => x.shift());
  // console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxx", x);


  var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  const person = {
    // playerbirthDate: "2019-03-01",
    playerbirthDate: this.props.cars.car2,
    multiYearNumber: 1,
    isMultiyearRecord: "Y",
    isMemberThresholdRecord: "N"
  }

  let playerEffectiveDetailsArray = [];

  dates.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    const me = Object.create(person);
    me.playerbirthDate = element;
    playerEffectiveDetailsArray.push(me.playerbirthDate);
  });

  console.log('playerEffectiveDetailsarray--->', playerEffectiveDetailsarray);
  //     let birthDateFiltered = this.props.cars.car2.filter(person => person.birthDate1 !== '' || person.birthDate1 !== undefined);

  //let birthDateFiltered = this.props.cars.car2.filter(person => person.birthDate1 !== '' || person.birthDate1 !== undefined);
  // console.log('car3 birthDateFiltered -->', birthDateFiltered);

  values.createdDate = current; //"15-01-2019";
  values.createdBy = 'jkjkjkjkjk';
  values.modifiedDate = current; //'16-01-2019';
  values.modifiedBy = 'jkjkjkjkjk';
  values.ball = '005391';
  values.playerStatus = 'PENDING';
  values.isActive = 'Y';
  values.ownerCode = 'FLB';
  values.playerType = this.props.cars.car1;
  values.playerEffectiveDetails = playerEffectiveDetailsarray;
  values.playerEffectiveDetails = [{
      // playerbirthDate: "2019-03-01",
      playerbirthDate: this.props.cars.car2,
      multiYearNumber: 1,
      isMultiyearRecord: "Y",
      isMemberThresholdRecord: "N"
    },
    {
      // playerbirthDate: "2019-03-01",
      playerbirthDate: this.props.cars.car2,
      multiYearNumber: 1,
      isMultiyearRecord: "Y",
      isMemberThresholdRecord: "N"
    },

    {
      isMultiyearRecord: "N",
      isMemberThresholdRecord: "Y",
      memberthresholdvalue: "2500"

    }
  ];

  delete values.terms;
  delete values.birthDate;
  console.log("car3 playerbirthDate values---->", values)



  axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${config.defaultUrl}/providerRates`,
      // data: sampleBenchMark,
      data: values,

      config: {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    })

    // axios.post(`${config.defaultUrl}/providerRates/nonHosp`, values)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('third car response.data--->', response.data);
      console.log('third car data playerID--->', response.data.playerID);

      this.props.setProps({
        loading: false,
        playerID: response.data.playerID
      });
      console.log('third car data playerbirthDateID--->', response.data.playerbirthDateID);
      this.props.setcarState({ ...this.props.cars,
        car3: response.data.playerbirthDateID
      })

      this.props.onNext();
    }).catch(err => {
      alert(`onSubmit Error\n${err}`);
      this.props.setProps({
        loading: false
      });
    });

  //this.props.onNext();
}
```

sample request

```
{

  "ball": "00539",
  "playerEvergreen": "Y",
  "playerMultiYear": "N",
  "playerType": "ANC",
  "playerStatus": "PENDING",
  "playerEffectiveDetails": [{

      "playerbirthDate": "2019-03-01",
      "multiYearNumber": 1,
      "isMultiyearRecord": "Y",
      "isMemberThresholdRecord": "N"


    },
    {

      "playerbirthDate": "2019-03-01",
      "multiYearNumber": 2,
      "isMultiyearRecord": "Y",
      "isMemberThresholdRecord": "N"


    },
    {

      "isMultiyearRecord": "N",
      "isMemberThresholdRecord": "Y",
      "memberthresholdvalue": "2500"


    }
  ],
  "isActive": "Y",
  "ownerCode": "FLB",
  "createdDate": "15-01-2019",
  "createdBy": "jkjkjkjkjk",
  "modifiedDate": "16-01-2019",
  "modifiedBy": "jkjkjkjkjk"

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - there is so much irrelevant code here and no runnable example (click edit an the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: @mplungjan hey updated the question...can you please help...I need to update the object inside an array with different values for each object